# jquery Event keeps executing, I want it to run only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, popupwindow

Please guys I need your help in executing this code only once, it keeps repeating each time I move my mouseover to the browser window.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    function myEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
      {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
      }
    }

    myEvent(document, "mouseleave", function (a) {
      var from = a.relatedTarget;
      if (a.pageY < $(window).scrollTop()) {
        $("#bounceModal").addClass("ffb-show");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: [jQuery.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) ? by the way, you are not using jquery "events" at all

Comment: In case you're unaware, Duke, Javascript and jQuery are not the same. Javascript is the language, jQuery is a popular library that most people use when using Javascript because it makes things easier.

Comment: Not what you're asking, but why on earth do you define `myEvent()` if you're also using jQuery? You could just say `$(document).on("mouseleave", function() {...})`.

Comment: @SankarRaj Why did you indent the whole code like that? Seems pointless to me. I also don't know if it's a good idea to add the closing `</script>` tag since it could indicate to us that the OP hasn't shown us all the code.

Comment: @Clonkex - The original version of the question included the closing script tag, but it wasn't indented properly so it didn't display. But yes, it would've been better to properly fix all of the indenting rather than just move everything to the right.

Comment: @Clonkex I didn't add anything. It was there. I just did ctrl + k.

Comment: @SankarRaj Apologies, I didn't look at the markup so couldn't see the tag. Weird that it was just invisible in the revisions though.

Comment: It has been corrected already.  I'm not a pro in javascript yet guys. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `{once:true}` to third parameter of `.addEventListener()`

```
  function myEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, {once:true});
  }
```

Comment: {once: true} should be the third parameter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener              obj.addEventListener(evt, fn,{once:true}, false);

Comment: @RajeshP Updated